# Bigcommerce show shipping method

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to add shipping method to product listing in the category page.
I tried to add `%%GLOBAL_ShippingPrice%%` to Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html but it doesn't work.
What is the proper method to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to add shipping providers?

```
%%GLOBAL_ShippingProviders%%
```

Comment: I want to add shipping method such as "free shipping", "$10 fixed shipping cost", etc.